# Store and query property history with Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-databases

I need to maintain a tree which contains nodes with attributes which are usually or strings, new attributes can be added to a node at runtime, etc. So a graph database like Neo4j is an obvious solution. But there is a slight twist: when an attribute is changed, I need to keep a record of its old value, and be able to efficiently query these old values (in particular, queries like "give me up 25 values of attribute X of node Y, starting from time Z" to support paging, and obviously "get latest value" needs to be efficient as well). What would be a good way to represent this?

Answer (score 1):

[`TimelineIndex`](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/index/lucene/TimelineIndex.html) almost gives what I need, except for limiting number of hits. But from JavaDoc of `IndexHits` it seems like it shouldn't matter too much if I iterate over as many as I need and then close the iterator.

So a solution looks like this: represent each property for which I need history as node instead; so instead of

```
Sensor
-----
name = "battery"
measurement = 1
```

I have

```
Sensor           attr
-----            -+--> name = "measurement"
name = "battery"  |    value = 1
                  |    timestamp = 100000000
                  |
                  +--> name = "measurement"
                  |    value = 2
                  |    timestamp = 100000001
                  |
                  +--> name = "measurement"
                       value = 1
                       timestamp = 100000002
```

And then I maintain a `TimelineIndex` for each `Sensor` node and each property-with-history.